# How to set type of variable on useState using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a variable named text and a hook named setText. I'm using it to change the value of a form input field.

How could I set that text will be of type string?

Here's what I did try:

```
interface TextInterface {
  text: string | null,
  setText: (value: string) => void,
}

const [ text, setText ] = useState<TextInterface>('');
```

But when doing it the following error is displayed: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TextInterface | (() => TextInterface)'.

It also display errors inside the input field and inside the handleText function (used on onchange inside input field).

The function:

```
const handleText = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    setText(e.currentTarget.value);
}
```

That displays the error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'

The input field:

```
<input type="text" value={ text } onChange={ handleText } />
```

Error:Type 'TextInterface' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.

Comment: Why not just use `useState('')`, given the string type can be inferred from the default value? And note that the generic argument to `useState` is the type of the _value_ being stored in state, not the type of the return value (which anyway is a tuple type, **not** an object type with `text` and `setText` properties - you're destructuring it by _position_, not name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const [ text, setText ] = useState<TextInterface>('');
```

You're close, but the `useState` generic doesn't expect you to pass in a type that describes both the state and the state-setter. You just need to specify the type of the state, as in:

```
const [ text, setText ] = useState<string | null>('');
```

If `null` wasn't a possibility, you could also leave off the explicit type, and typescript would infer the type to be `string`

```
const [ text, setText ] = useState('');
```